# Angular 1.5 - Insert custom element after last element with certain property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's assume I'm having following code:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in todoList">
    {{task.name}}
</li>
```

And let's assume this is my dataset ( Assuming it's ordered by when, from now to future ) :

```
var todoList = [ { name : 'Work hard', when : 'Today'}, { name : 'Play hard', when : 'Today'}, { name : 'Relax hard', when : 'This week'}, ]
```

How can I detect in the ng-repeat when the current repeated item is the last item with the property when set to Today ?

So I'll end up something with something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="task in todoList">
    {{task.name}}
</li>
<!-- If last of current period, then show this -->
<li>
    <h3>Next period</h3>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try grouping the data by `when`, and repeating on the result set:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(when, tasks) in todoList | groupBy: 'when'">
  When: {{ when }}
  <li ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
    <span ng-hide="$last">{{task.name}}</span>
    <h3 ng-show="$last">Next period</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit 1:**

If you just want to show the data of **Today**, you can just filter out the `todoList`, and then render it:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in todoList | filter:{ when: 'Today' }">
  <span ng-hide="$last">{{task.name}}</span>
  <h3 ng-show="$last">Next period</h3>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a method that checks if the current item is the last today:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in todoList">
    <div ng-switch="lastToday(task)">
        <div ng-switch-when="false">{{task.name}}</div>
        <h3 ng-switch-when="true">Next period</h3>
    </div>
</li>

$scope.lastToday = function(task) {
    return ($scope.todoList.reverse().find(t => t.when === 'Today') || {} ).name === task.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<li ng-repeat="task in todoList" ng-show="!$last">
    {{task.name}}
</li>
  <li ng-repeat="task in todoList" ng-show="$last">
   <h3>Next period</h3>
</li>
```

**$last** will help on this

Comment: I'm afraid $last doesn't work, because I've got multiple periods in the list, and after each period, I'd like to insert an extra <li>

Comment: Wouldn't work for my use case, this assumes there are only two periods available and it assumes only the last item in the list belongs to a different period...

Comment: <li ng-repeat="task in todoList" ng-show="!$last || task.when != 'Today'">
    {{task.name}}
</li>
  <li ng-repeat="task in todoList" ng-show="$last && task.when == 'Today'">
   <h3>Next period</h3>
</li>